# SVN: How to commit old local code back to an existing branch?

Tags: svn

I have a problem:

- I created A branch (svn version 1880) from the trunk to create a release branch.
- Due to user-requests I modified the branch heavily without up-porting the code to the trunk. The branch is now on version 1949.
- The working code 1949 has major modifications compared with the trunk
- The working code 1949 was checked out to a colleague's workspace. He is running that code, which fulfills his needs.
- I updated the trunk code with code of branch version 1949 and continued developing in the trunk.
- At some point, due to my inability to handle SVN properly, I overwrote (and committed) the release branch with the new trunk code. The branch version is 2170 now.
- I do not have the 2170 code locally on a machine.

However, I need to have the branch back at version 1949 again. I copied the relevant code from my colleague's workspace to my machine. I can run it without problems.

--> How do I overwrite version 2170 in SVN with the local code of version 1949?

Comment: Have you tried the command `svn merge -r 2170:1949` on your working copy of branch (then commit) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not really "overwrite version 2170 in SVN with the local code of version 1949", as you wrote.
What you can do is to commit some modifications in branch, in order that the next revision of branch will have exactly the same content as the old revision 1949. And you can do this by running this command **on your working copy of branch**:

```
svn merge -r 2170:1949
```

Then check local modifications and commit. This will create a new revision (2171 or more) in which the branch will have the same content as the old revision 1949.

Comment: Hi Laurent, thank for your comment, but unfortunately it didn't work - I guess I did something wrong as I am struggeling VERY MUCH with SVN.
Still, I found a solution: 1) I checked out my version 2170 from SVN. 2) Then in the local copy I deleted all content but the ".*" hidden directories. 3) Then I copied all but ".*" content from local copy of 1949 to directory 2170. 4) in local directory of 2170 I performed a commit which worked and created a version 2171.

Comment: @WolfiG When you write "it didn't work", can you detail what happened ? Remember that you had to run the `svn merge` command on a working copy of the branch updated to revision 2170, i.e. the HEAD revision. (ouch, you performed it the hard way !)

Comment: Hi Laurent, sorry, but I don't really remember what the message was. I remember that I ran the svn merge on the working copy but ran into errors. As I was under time pressure I didn't investigate the error. Anyhow, thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laurents post (which didn't work for me in the way Laurent described it), I managed to perform the following workaround:

Start situation:

- I do have a local copy of code version 1949 in my local workspace
- I do have a checked in version of version 2170 in SVN

Then I did the following:

1. I checked out 2170 from SVN to local workspace
2. In local copy of 2170 I deleted all content but hidden ".*"
3. Then in local directory of 1949 I copied all 1949-code to the 2170 directory
4. Switched to 2170 directory
5. Performed a commit with this "updated" code --> version 2171 in SVN

What I still have to do is to manually delete unnecessary 2170-files in SVN.